# PolarArea ApexChart unexpected behaviour

Tags: vuejs3, apexcharts

I want to create a polar area chart in my vue3 app using ApexCharts.js. I use options object from the apexchart docs, but it doesn't work. What I get is just a skeleton for the polar area chart with x and y axis'. I use  syntax. Exactly the same setup works fine for a bar-chart. I wonder if there are any issues with polarArea chart for vue3?

```
<script setup lang="ts">

const props = defineProps({
data: {
    type: Array<number>,
    required: true
}
 })

const series = ref([{ 
name: 'Wind Rose',
data: props.windRoseData.map((data) => data * 100)
}])

const options = {
    series: props.windRoseData.map((data) => data * 100),
    chart: {
    type: 'polarArea',
},
stroke: {
    colors: ['#fff']
},
fill: {
    opacity: 0.8
},
responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 480,
    options: {
    chart: {
        width: 200
    },
    legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
    }
    }
}]
};
</script>

<template>
  <div id="chart">
    <apexchart :options="options" :series="series" type="polarArea" />
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `series` data must be a simple array of values and not an object.  This format is specific to [Data for Pie/Donuts/RadialBars](https://apexcharts.com/docs/series/#data-for-pie-donuts)

> The series expects a single array for pie/donut and radialbar charts. The names of the series values are to be provided in labels property.

Change your `series` to:

```js
const series = ref(props.windRoseData.map((data) => data * 100))
```

It may just be a typo in your question, but you're using `props.windRoseData` here but you've defined the prop as `props.data`, so you may need to correct that.

Also, `options` should not have it's own separate `series` property. Remove it. Finally, if you want labels for your series data you should add the `labels` property here.

```js
const options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'polarArea'
  },
  labels: ['label 1', 'label 2', 'etc...'],
  stroke: {
    colors: ['#fff']
  },
  ... // more options
}
```

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-lederberg-dclmgj?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you. And yes, it was a typo

Comment: No problem! If the answer is satisfactory, please remember to mark it as correct. Thanks